# Index text files in solr line by line

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

I have a text file. First of all how can I index it? Also there are some specific terms in file, I want to do parsing of this files also i.e. if I index a TEXT file, its content is saved as it is , is it parsed by solr or not?

If not paresed (for some unique terms in text file) then how can I do it.
I have come to know that by using script post.sh, you can index it, but it is only for xml files and not for text files!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a technical question. You need to step back and ask yourself what you want to **find**. Does one file correspond to one result or to many. If many, then what is *a result*.

Then, you have to see where the files are coming from. Are you pushing them into Solr or getting Solr to pull them (from database or filesystem).

This gives you a way to figure out how to ask much better and more specific question. For example, to read the file line by line in a pull fashion, you may want to look at the [DataImportHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) with FileDataSource and LineEntityProcessor.